# Where is source code of QGIS Processing algorithms?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am beginning to learn QGIS 3 up from QGIS 2.  I see many changes.

In QGIS 2 one could find the scripts for the algorithms located in the Processing Toolbox but in QGIS 3 I cannot find them (for example, `RandomExtract.py` file).

Can someone direct me to the path?

Answer (score 6):

### QGIS processing Python scripts

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/b6a7a1070329a1f167341e3187781954d28f2f39/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis

### QGIS processing C++ scripts

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/a198e30488d93b94ba0f43d3ec898feea06027da/src/analysis/processing

---

In particular, the `RandomExtract` algorithm is here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/a198e30488d93b94ba0f43d3ec898feea06027da/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmrandomextract.cpp

---

Note: Many of the previous Python scripts have been migrated to C++.